# Calculate distance between successive points along polyline where points lie on the polyline in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have multiple points (shapefile of points layer) and polyline layer. These multiple points are on the polyline layer. How can I calculate distance between multiple points along polyline in ArcGIS? I want distance between successive points from bottom right to upper left or vice versa.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Questions here should not only give a description of the task, but also describe the effort undertaken to accomplish to goal, and the problem encountered. Please [Edit] the question to specify the exact release of ArcGIS in use, and which of the two Desktop apps (ArcMap and ArcGIS Pro) you are using. Please also confirm that you want the network distance between stops and that you have a license for Network Analyst.

Comment: i am using ARCMAP 10.3.I want distance between successive points along polyline.how to get license?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. It would be exceedingly difficult to obtain a new license for 10.3, since it's already in Mature support status, and due to be retired in 3.5 months. You can solve this without Network Analyst, but it would be best if you had advanced Python skills with lots of ArcPy experience.